# Disabled option in Firefox bug

Tags: debugging, firefox, cross-browser

I was creating some form when I saw that in Firefox. In a select box, if you add a disabled option as first choice... it select the next available option

```
<option disabled="disabled" value="false">Choose option</option>
<option value="1">Value 1</option>
```

It will select "Value 1" when the page is loaded.

Why every browser will select the disabled one by default and Firefox not?

Load this in Firefox : http://jsfiddle.net/6WjgZ/1/

and other browser you'll notice that Firefox bypass the disabled one and select the "Value 1" by default.

Comment: Interesting, I had never noticed that!

Comment: Yeah and it mess up my ajax forms because it think that there's always a value selected !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want a workaround, run this code on DOM Load (or body load) to fix it in Firefox

```
document.getElementById("mySel").selectedIndex = 0;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6WjgZ/2/

Not sure if this can be called a bug (more of a behavior style), if you think about it, FF doesn't let you choose disabled items. Neither does other browsers (except IE) but then, they choose to behave differently for the initial load.

Comment: Firefox used to be a great developer's browser but now... I dunno what they are thinking.

Comment: Agree with you 100%. Now that lead Firebug dev has joined google, I guess Chrome will be overtaking it soon (I like FB better than Chrome's dev tools but they are catching up!).

Comment: I accepted this answer only because it's a workaround, if anyone could find the reason why Firefox want to start that stupid thing, please let me know :D

Comment: The selected and disabled attributes aren't mutially exclusive, so an easier workaround is just to write `<option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="false">Choose option</option>` to begin with.  The "choose option" entry will be initially selected, and the user will not be able to click it in the dropdown box.  **However**, even if the user doesn't ever touch the dropdown, Firefox will _still_ report the first non-disabled option as being "selected" in the DOM, even though visually that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

you could use optgroup if you want a non-selectable option, or simply use the value for form validation.

if all you want is the disabled style, you could give the option a class and change it with css

i think ff behaviour is right, a disabled option should not be a valid option. you can always file it as a bug in mozilla