# Firefox making automatic selection when input is sorted with jQuery

Tags: jquery, firefox, jquery-ui-sortable

In Firefox 32 I have a `<select>` where the first `<option>` is both `disabled` and `selected` like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>jQuery sortable() error Firefox</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $(".sort").sortable({
          items: "> div"
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="sort">
      <div>
        <h1>Heading</h1>
        <select>
          <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Make a selection</option>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1>Heading</h1>
        <select>
          <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Make a selection</option>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I click on the input to open the drop-down and hover over one of the valid options *but don't select it* and then click off the input, at first the greyed out option shows again, but if I drag the heading immediately above it, the last option pointed at becomes selected. This only happens in Firefox, not in Chrome or Google-Opera or even IE. How do I keep it as not selected in Firefox until the user directly selects it?

### EDIT

It looks like this is unrelated to jQuery and sortable, they merely show the behaviour "under the hood" of Firefox. The following code shows the bug much more succinctly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Firefox select bug</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="get">
      <select name="test">
        <option value="0" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Make a selection</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Simply point to an option but don't select it, then submit the form. You should see `?test=[value]` at the end of the address where `[value]` is whichever option you pointed to last.

Comment: See the discussion on this behavior here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903131/disabled-option-in-firefox-bug

Comment: After reading closer, that doesn't really help, but just says that it's a long standing functionality choice by Firefox. Sorry.

Comment: @ClaytonLeis That's slightly different... their code doesn't have `selected="selected"`. I think user agents are expected to select an option if none are specified in the HTML so the first enabled one makes sense. My code works just fine (i.e. as expected) if the user never points to an option without selecting it. So while the disabled option is selected: open select, close select -> no value chosen (correct behaviour); open select, click an option -> value correctly chosen; open select, point to option, close select -> value incorrectly chosen.

Comment: I see. I don't know what you can do about it though. My guess is there is a bug submitted to Mozilla if you want to look it up and see what they are saying about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is either a bug or desired behaviour in Firefox. As far as I know there is no programmatic way to distinguish between Firefox's automatic selection and an intentional human initiated selection, i.e. from within JavaScript the automatic selection looks just like clicking to select the option, etc.